# How to make a classifier(TrainingSet) for countries and it's capitals?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, training-data

i want to detect if a sentence contains country name or a capital(i.e. Egypt,Cairo,USA,Washongton,India,newdelhi,Kewit,Trablos,Paris,etc..) i want to make a file contains all the countries names and it's capitals and make a binary search on that file to see if there's any match,any idea on how to get a ready (Classifier)that makes a binary search or any kind of search on the data file will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of a list of countries and itz capital and some more info is available but it is sql database file. http://www.joombah.com/downloads/view.download/23

Hope this database helps you in solving your problem